# Parsing special characters (e.g., è, é, and ®) JSONs in Play for Scala (version 2.3.x)

Tags: json, scala, encoding, utf-8, playframework-2.0

I am having problems when parsing special characters (e.g., è, é, and ®) JSONs in Play for Scala (version 2.3.x).  Since everything in Play is UTF-8 encoded it should not be a problem with the aforementioned examples (è, é, and ®). I should mention that I am using IntelliJ and sbt for my development.

I have verified the following:

- test file is UTF-8 encoded
- javac using utf-8 (javacOptions ++= Seq("-encoding", "UTF-8"))
- setting utf-8 on header (application/json; charset=utf-8)
- parse.tolerantJson(request) is the culprit of the error (see code below)

Test file:

```
{"id":"295b1590-220a-11e4-b641-90e08f355b68","blah":"è é ®"}
```

Controller:

```
      def putGuid(streamId: String, guid: UUID) = Action.async(parseToEventContent) {
    implicit request =>
      render.async {
        case mimeType@(Accepts.Json()) =>
          val id = msgId.next()
          (request.body match {
            case JsonEventContent(j) =>
              eventActor ? SendEventMessages.SendJsonEvent(id, streamId, Some(guid), remoteAddress(request), j)
            case ... some other cases...
          }) map {
            case SendEventMessages.Done(`id`) => NoContent
            case ... more error cases.. blah blah ...
            case SendEventMessages.Unknown(`id`) =>
              Logger.info("Message ID: {}. Received an unknown from underlying actors", id.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
              ServiceUnavailableRetryAfter()
          } recover exceptionErrorHandler
      } }
```

Where the BodyParser is:

```
  trait EventContent {}
  case class JsonEventContent(data: JsValue) extends EventContent

  def parseToEventContent: BodyParser[EventContent] = BodyParser("eventContent") {
    request =>
      import play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution.Implicits.trampoline
      request.contentType match {
        case Some(MimeTypes.JSON) => parse.tolerantJson(request).map(_.right.map(JsonEventContent(_)))
        case _ => Done(Left(UnsupportedMediaType), Empty)
      }
  }
```

Edit #1

using something like the below in my test gives me the 400 error for "èé®" but 204 for "abc" (my source files are utf-8 and javac is set to use uff-8 in build.sbt):

```
val eventC = Json.parse(new String(s"""{"id":"295b1590-220a-11e4-b641-90e08f355b68","blah":"è é ®"}""".getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"))
val eventCJson = eventC.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")

"return 204 when entity has è, é, ® in json event" in new WithApplication(MyFakeApplication()){
  println(s"json=${eventC}")
  val result = assertPutRequest(s"/streams/com.gilt.clickstream/events/295b1590-220a-11e4-b641-90e08f355b68", 204, event = eventCJson, "application/json", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
  contentType(result) must be equalTo None
  contentAsBytes(result) must be equalTo Array()
}

def assertPutRequest(url: String, httpStatus: Int, event: Array[Byte], acceptHeader: String = "application/json", contentTypeHeader: String = "application/json; charset=utf-8")(implicit app: Application) = {
  Akka.system.actorOf(MockEventActor.props, "event")

  val result = route(
    FakeRequest(PUT, url)
      .withHeaders(
        "Accept" -> acceptHeader,
        "Content-Type" -> contentTypeHeader)
      .withRawBody(event)
  )(new Writeable({ j: AnyContentAsRaw => j.raw.asBytes().get}, None)).get

  status(result) must be equalTo httpStatus
  result
}
```

Comment: Which version of Play?

Comment: Try your data with the existing [integration tests in Play](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-integration-test/src/test/scala/play/it/http/parsing/JsonBodyParserSpec.scala), I do successfully get the following `JsObject`: `{"id":"295b1590-220a-11e4-b641-90e08f355b68","blah":"è é ®"}`

Comment: Odd, yes I can get that to work too. However, using something like the above Edit #1 in my test gives me the 400 error for "èé®" but 204 for "abc"

Comment: JDK 1.6 was the culprit, upgrading to 1.7 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to upgrade to JDK 1.7.  I was using JDK 1.6 and that caused the issue.